# How to use iframe in dash/plotly? (Python/HTML)

Tags: python, html, iframe, dashboard, plotly-dash

I'm creating a dashboard and I want to use this interactive map

web link: https://www.ons.gov.uk/peoplepopulationandcommunity/healthandsocialcare/causesofdeath/articles/deathsinvolvingcovid19interactivemap/2020-06-12

embedded code:
`<iframe height="1043px" width="100%" src="https://www.ons.gov.uk/visualisations/dvc914/map/index.html"></iframe>`

Now I don't know that much HTML but this is what I have so far. I know the layout is wrong but I have been stuck for quite a while now, could anyone point me in the right direction. Many thanks!

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)


#H1 = biggest heading,  Div = a box containhg info
app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.H1(children='Hello Dash'),

    html.Div(children='''
        Dash: A web application framework for Python.
    '''),

    dcc.Graph(
        id='example-graph',
        figure=fig
        
    <iframe height="1067px" width="100%" src="https://www.ons.gov.uk/visualisations/dvc914/map/index.html"></iframe>
    )
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True,port=8049,host='127.0.0.1')
```

Answer (score 6):

You're almost there. Just replace the <> syntax for the iframe element with the dash syntax that you used for the other elements,

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']
app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.H1(children='Hello Dash'),

    html.Div(children='''
        Dash: A web application framework for Python.
    '''),

    dcc.Graph(
        id='example-graph',
        # figure=fig  # commented out to make the example runnable
    ),

    html.Iframe(src="https://www.ons.gov.uk/visualisations/dvc914/map/index.html",
                style={"height": "1067px", "width": "100%"})
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, port=8049, host='127.0.0.1')
```

Comment: How do I get the height to wrap the entire HTML instead of specifying the exact pixel?