# Local HTML file won't load properly into Dash application

Tags: python, html, css, path, plotly-dash

I've tried to embed a local html file into a basic Dash App.
I used the code in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64736956/how-to-use-iframe-in-dash-plotly-python-html) and replaced the path with my local relative path (the dash app is in the same folder as the html local page)

```
html.Iframe(src="random_example.html",
            style={"height": "1067px", "width": "100%"})
```

but this is the result I get: [image: html.H1 repeats in one another]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could put the html file in the `assets` folder and reference it like this:

```
import dash
import dash_html_components as html

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div(
    children=[
        html.Iframe(
            src="assets/random_example.html",
            style={"height": "1067px", "width": "100%"},
        )
    ]
)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: [SOLVED]
 Wow, huge thanks! I was stuck for quite a while and simply moving the HTML files to assets actually made it work. Curious as to why, without putting the file in assets, it doesn't work but still, thank you !

Comment: Hello, what do you mean by assets folder please ? I've tried src="assets/my_file.html" but nothing is happening. Maybe I have to define assets=something before using it in src="assets/my_file.html" ? Thank you ! @Bas van der Linden

Comment: @MarionEtp You have to create the assets folder if you haven't already. Create it inside the root directory (the folder your app is in), then put your file in the assets folder. See https://dash.plotly.com/dash-enterprise/static-assets for official documentation on this.

Comment: @5eb I noticed that that documentation page is meant for Dash Enterprise. Can static HTML files also be included in projects that use the open-source version of Dash rather than the enterprise version?

Comment: @KBurchfiel Yes. I have never used Dash Enterprise myself. The enterprise version link was the first to show up for some reason so that's why I used it. But it's mentioned in the general documentation as well https://dash.plotly.com/external-resources

Comment: @5eb Great, thank you for clarifying that!